# formatting in Dreamweaver using the dropdowns

Tags: dreamweaver

if I want to format a small snippet of text using the dropdowns (ie Heading 1, 2 paragraph), it often ends up changing the tag for a large snippet of text (or even half the page). [image]

How do i change this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When used like this the property inspector will expand the selection to include the parent tag of the selected text, causing the selected option in the property inspector (p, h1, h2, etc) to replace the parent tag with the selected option. you cannot change this operation.

You can make a selection, hit CTRL+T (CMD+T I assume on Mac) which brings up the Wrap Tag editing option, type your tag, then hit enter and the selection will be wrapped with the tag of your choice.

Comment: thanks, that looks like it's as close as i can expect from DW.

Answer (score 1):

When you select part of a tag in Dreamweaver and change the format, DW will change the format of the parent tag.

What you are describing requires a different technique as you are trying to get inline formatting.  You need to select the text and then wrap it with a span tag (Danilo's advice is correct in that regard).  You then apply the CSS style you want to the span tag to change the format.

So to style **No longer want to receive these updates** it would look like so:

```
<p>No longer <span style="font-size:18px;">want</span> to receive these updates?</p>
```

After DW gets through with it.  In Design View after wrapping the text with span, select in the Tag Inspect and switch the Property Bar to CSS mode to style.